# Splint and MySQL: Null storage passed as non-null param

Tags: mysql, c, splint

I'm trying to use Splint with a short CGI script, but get this error:

`Null storage passed as non-null param: mysql_init(NULL)`

`mysql_init` is defined to return a new value if it's param is `NULL`, or store the result in the param if it's not. Yet, if I try

```
MYSQL* connection;
mysql_init(connection);
```

I will get:

`Variable connection used before definition`

How to resolve this? One way would of course be to annotate `mysql.h` so Splint won't complain. Is the my only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may either edit `mysql.h` to annotate that parameter as `/*@null@*/`, or deactivate the warning *for that specific line of code*:

```
/*@-nullpass@*/
connection = mysql_init(NULL);
/*@=nullpass@*/
```

By the way, be careful not to pass uninitialized variables to functions:

```
MYSQL* connection; /* this pointer contains garbage at this point */
mysql_init(connection); /* this may get a segmentation fault */
```

Instead, you should be doing:

```
MYSQL* connection = NULL; /* initialize to NULL */
connection = mysql_init(connection); /* get a hold of the new object created */
```